Impossible to connect my LND node to my (separate) bitcoin node
I'm trying to connect manage my lnd node and my bitcoin node as 2 separated vm (for disaster recovery efficiency).
Bitcoin is in v28.0
Lnd is in v0.18.3
Both VMs are hosted on the same Proxmox.
Blockchain is fully synced on bitcoin node.
I used sshfs for sharing the /data/bitcoin repository with my lnd node.
Problem : I tried to modify bitcoin.conf and lnd.conf, in order to set-up connection between the 2 servers and having lnd rpc parameters pointing to my bitcoin node, but it fails.
That is, when I run lnd on my lnd node, it goes to "wallet unlocked", but then nothing is happening. Logs file does not say more information.
Did anybody encounter such issue?
